# Showing $h(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_x^{x+\epsilon} f(t)dt$ is differentiable for continuous $f$ and $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

> Assume $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $h(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_x^{x+\epsilon} f(t)dt$. Show $h$ is differentiable and $h'$ is continuous. Compute $h'$.

I think we must use fundamental theorem of calculus.

$f$ continuous implies $f$ integrable.

Comment: What is the derivative of $h(x) = \displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$?

Comment: Not a bad problem i think-- can be seen as an exercise of visual thinking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\int_a^x f(t)dt = G(x)$, then $h(x) = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} (G(x+\varepsilon) - G(x))$

$h'(x) = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} (G'(x+\varepsilon) - G'(x)) = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}(f(x+\varepsilon) - f(x))$.